# window object внутри js класса

Tags: javascript

Имеется js class. Возможно ли внутри класса отслеживать изменился размер window или нет, и если изменилось применять метод класса? 
Проблема: в классе создаются span элементы на определенных позициях, а при ресайзе окна метки сдвигаются. Хотел очищать метки при изменении окна, но внутри класса. Подскажите советом.

Comment: событие `resize`

Comment: @ThisMan, да но window объект не видно внутри класса. На чем ресайз проверять?

Comment: _да но window объект не видно внутри класса_ это вы как такое удумали?)

Comment: `window` видно везде, если вы код в браузере выполняете. Это как глобальный объект, доступный из любого контекста

Comment: @ThisMan, когда я обращаюсь к window внутри класса, например так : 
    
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() { //метод класса  });

Comment: добавьте код, который не работает в вопрос)

Comment: @ThisMan, у меня все получилось, спасибо) создал метод класса resize и в нем обращался к window и вроде все норм, спасибо за ваше время.

Comment: вы напишите все равно ответ на вопрос. Кому-то еще это может помочь)

Answer (score 1):

Свою проблему решил, добавив в имеющийся метод init обработчик для window. Вдруг кому-то поможет.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 10;
  }
  init() {
    const mark = document.createElement('span');
    mark.className = 'ttt';
    mark.innerHTML = 'test' + this.x; 
    document.body.appendChild(mark);
    // Если изменили размер окна
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.f = this.destroy.bind(this)); 
  }
  destroy() {
    const mark = document.querySelectorAll('.ttt');
    mark.forEach(element => {
      element.remove();
    }); console.log(this.f);
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.f); 
  }
  
}

const t = new Test();
t.init();
```

```css
.ttt {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: без доп метода можно было обойтись)  сразу в `init` написать

Comment: @Да я понял) просто думал так наглядней.

Comment: тогда лучше назвать метод по другому, сейчас кажется, что он уже ресайзит что-то, а он на самом деле просто навешивает обработчик

Comment: @ThisMan, поправил)

Comment: каждый объект создаст по функции-слушателю

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не понял вас, есть ошибка?

Comment: @Odyssey window.addEventListener добавляет слушатель, который Вы нигде не убираете, если создать и удалить 100500 Ваших объектов в окне останутся их слушатели

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, понял.  Правильным ли будет если в методе destroy() буду удалять слушатель?  window.removeEventListener('resize', function () {
      this.destroy();
    }.bind(this));

Comment: да, но немного не так, нужно сохранить ссылку на слушатель, а потом удалить его же, а не новую функцию передавать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, код в ответе поправил, примерно так?

Comment: @Odyssey bind возвращает новую функцию, через = присвойте addEventListener(“”, this.func = f.bind...), a потом удаляйте this.func

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, извините, не понял вас(

Comment: @Odyssey буду у компа - напишу

Comment: `class Test {
  init() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.f = this.destroy.bind(this));
  }
  destroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.f);
  }
}`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, поправил, спасибо за помощь.